# How to change a subsiste url

Tags: url

We want to change the name of a tab (subsite).  How do we change the associated url when this is done to reflect the new name? This is Sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 4):

You can do this through the browser. Go to Title, Description and Icon in the site settings of the subsite and change it there.

Comment: easily done via the browser like you say, easy to do and can really cause havoc if your users aren't expecting it :-)